# Short film titled with a variant of "Vampire"

Tags: story-identification, horror, short-film

I saw this short film back in the days when you'd go to the cinema and there were always two or three shorts before the main feature.

My memory is very sparse, but here's what I've got:

- I *think* I saw it when I saw *[Ghost Story](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Story_(1981_film))*, which would make it 1981. Definitely sometime in the early '80s.
- The film was about ten minutes long, and the title was some variant of the word "Vampire". Something like "Wamphyr" or "Vampyr".
- There was an oldish book with that word as its title, in large creepy letters on the cover. To the best of my recollection, there were no vampires in the film, and the book was the only supernatural thing in it.
- The book could fly of its own volition, using its covers to flap like wings.
- It may have been sentient. It certainly targeted a human for spooky persecution.
- The film ended when the book flew into the back of its target, knocking him/her over a balcony and (maybe) killing them.

Comment: Mayhaps this one? Runtime 25 minutes? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4834598/

Comment: @jo1storm difficult to be definitive given the sparsity of information, but doesn't look like it. That appears to be a documentary about vampire bats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have just seen your enquiry from several months ago - the film is called Vampyr, and I think it was made in 1981. I saw it with The Hunger, fittingly, in 1983, and recall the flapping book cover 'wings'. I think there was also a scene where the reader was crawling along the floor and the camera tilted, giving the aspect of Dracula climbing his castle walls. I wrote a brief booklet/monograph on short British horror films in 2019 and included a slight reminiscence about the film (not much more than I've said here). I think the director was called Gordon Pinter or Punter. I did see Ghost Story at the cinema, in the ATV Midlands region, but this short didn't play with that movie in our area, though it is possible it may have done elsewhere.

Information about the short film can be found [at google books](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=1c7eCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA896&lpg=PA896&dq=%22gordon%20pinter%22%20vampyr&source=bl&ots=e8F_IrnGsD&sig=ACfU3U288dBR6XN44JeXLkX9b2l_TXZ6ZQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9vfuI3dP3AhXmRmwGHXv8DUQQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22gordon%20pinter%22%20vampyr&f=false), at [the British Film Institute](https://www2.bfi.org.uk/films-tv-people/4ce2b7828ab22), and [here](http://www.smguariento.com/take-an-uneasy-ride-british-theatrical-horror-shorts-1976-83-by-sim-branaghan/). The latter link includes a picture of the director and the flying book remembered by the OP.

[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  I can't find a movie of that title in that time frame.  (1932 seems _too_ early.)  Can you find a link to the movie somewhere?  (I can't find a record of a Pinter or a Punter at IMDB either; the closest I can find is "George Pintér" and none of his movies fit the subject matter or time frame.)

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you. A few google searches provided me with enough information to satisfy me that it is the one I remember. I've added that information to your answer. A pity it's so obscure, I'd have liked  link so I could see it again.

Answer (score 4):

[This tweet](https://twitter.com/trendylefty/status/1715018705036324945) from Lawrence Monk mentions a range of films that were used as double-features. *Vampyr* by Gordon Punter is listed as supporting *The Hunger* (1981).

> *This is a list of UK horror shorts used as double features. They
> officially ended in 1983 but I'm sure some were dusted off as a filler
> years after. Pretty obscure some of these.*
>
> [image]

Comment: This reads like a comment on the [existing answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/262941/122024), which has already been [confirmed as correct](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/254015/short-film-titled-with-a-variant-of-vampire#comment734556_262941) by the OP. As such, it would've been better to post this as a comment on that answer, rather than an answer in its own right, in my opinion. That said, you've not yet earned the 50 reputation score required to do that.

Comment: @LogicDictates - It's definitely an answer, but you're not wrong that this should have probably been posted as a comment.